# Error in Google finance API

Tags: google-api, google-finance, currency-exchange-rates

I want to convert currencies using google finance api. But its not working in my local machine(India). 
It works fine when I hit from one server located in USA and provides proper result.

Url : https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=ZAR&to=USD&meta=53336452-3e60-4fa1-9740-9ef8ea9e9118

Can anyone please help me to work this api properly in my local machine?

Any help will be appriciated
Thanks.

Comment: The above url will redirect user to search page as it returns with status 302, and next page to redirect information (this url is google search url in this case).

Comment: alternative service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance/21518807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was facing the similar issue (**Google Converter API suddenly not
>   working**)

As per my finding, I got the solution and conclude here that Google recently update the finance API.
The below link is work for me

**Latest URL:** https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter

```
file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
```

Comment: this url is not working anymore, do you have the latest url?